# Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.PointerPosition

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm writing a Windows 10 universal app. I use `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.PointerPosition` to read pointer position every 30 ms. It works perfectly on desktop, but doesn't work on a tablet  which has only a touch interface (Windows 10 Home installed) - why is it so and in what way can I read pointer position so it works on desktop on tablet? I know I could use event `UIElement.PointerMoved` event, but that would involve changing lots of code, so I would prefer some method/property that allows to read pointer position in DispathcerTimer's tick event - like `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.PointerPosition`.

Comment: Try to start your Timer on `PointerPressed` event and stop on `PointerReleased` event. It will help to resolve your problem?

Comment: Well, there is no pointer is there?  The user's index finger isn't constantly pressed against the glass.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem